# How to prepare and compare two dataframes in Pandas with unaligned datasets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new to stackoverflow as well as Python and Pandas so please forgive formating issues in this question. I am thankfull for all friendly comments, since I would like to to learn and use the data comparison possibilities.

I have two .xlsx files, which i convert to dataframes df1 and d2 using python and pandas.

Lets say both look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
def main():
data1 = {"Col1":["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5"], "Col2":["Street1", "Street2", "Street3", "Street4", "Street5"], "Col3":["Phone1", "Phone2", "Phone3", "Phone4", "Phone5"],}
data2 = {"Col1":["Name1", "Name3", "New", "Name5", "New2", "Name6"], "Col2":["Street1", "Street3", "New", "Street5", "New2", "Street6"], "Col3":["Phone1", "Phone3", "New", "Phone5", "New2", "Street6"],}    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Both have the same structure **but** both contain as well two empty rows following a row, that contains a header (not shown in the code example).

At first these rows and the header need to be ignored, by default (start at row=4).
Then I need to compare df1 and df2 to find the rows, that are NOT in df2 by an index like "Col1" (here 2nd and 4th row from d1).

Those should be printed with a comment like:

"df2.Name2", "df2.Name4": gone" or similar, be saved to a .xlsx file and 
be dropped to create a new dataframe df3

Afterwards I need to find new entries in df2 that are not in df3 and extract these new rows to another .xlsx file.

I further would like to create a fourth dataframe df4 with data from df3 plus empty rows where new entries were found in df2 that looks like:

```
data4 = {"Col1":["Name1", "Name3", " ", "Name5", " ", "Name6"], "Col2":["Street1", "Street3", " ", "Street5", " ", "Street6"], "Col3":["Phone1", "Phone3", " ", "Phone5", " ", "Name6"]}
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data4)
print(df4)
```

Now the similar data of df2 and df4 are in the same rows again and can be compared in a next step to find changes in some columns (not shown in the example).

I tried to create some codes using the concentate or merge functions but since the deleted and new rows change the order of the lines the "alike" data are not aligned anymore and the result is way too high, so the described data preparation is my main problem.

Many thanks in advance for your help.